# Знаки препинания корректны?

Tags: запятые, прямая-речь

*Арсений открывает ему дверь: «Привет, мой милый друг», — и сам плачет, и друг его плачет.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствие на бумаге станет читабельнее, если приставить к нему восклицательный знак.
(Предложение, чтобы его окончание не воспринималось как обычное перечисление, закончил бы раньше).

*Арсений открывает ему дверь: «Привет, мой милый друг!» — и сам плачет. И друг его плачет.*